# Correct Date and Time using Python

Tags: python, linux, csv, datetime

I have a .csv file with a lot of dates and times (around 3000 rows). And all the rows are like:

```
#Arrival_Date#  #Arrival_Time#  #Departure_Date#  #Departure_Time#    
2017/01/01      23:30           2017/01/01        00:30
2017/02/01      23:30           2017/02/01        23:40
2017/03/01      15:45           2017/03/01        17:30
2017/04/10      23:50           2017/04/10        00:30
```

But my problem is: I need to correct the date on Departure_Date (2017/01/02 and 2017/04/11).

Is there a way to do this automatically? My professor told me to use Python, but I have no idea how.

Any suggestions about where should I start?

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: Are the second and third columns always one day after the first?

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not necessarily @chrisz I can have 2017/01/01 08:30    2017/01/01 09:30    2017/01/01 10:50. I'm trying to provide a better example but I don't know how to create tables here.

Comment: @U8-Forward First I filtered the dates and times near midnight using excel. It was a bit toilful, but worked. But now I need something more simple.

Comment: @U8-Forward I thought about open the .csv as csvFile and create a ** for ** for read the column, but I do not know how can I compare the time to add 1 day when it's need.

Comment: use [datetime](https://pymotw.com/3/datetime/) module

Comment: Use the [edit] button to add extra information into your question rather than trying to provide it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a day to the departure date if the departure is before the arrival. To do this you would need to use Python's `datetime` library. Start by combining the date and time components into a single string and then converting the string into a datetime object. You can then do a simple comparison to determine if one date is before another. If this is the case, use `timedelta` to a day to the departure date. Next convert this back into date string and update the third column (i.e. `row[2]`). The updated data can then be written back to a seperate CSV file:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv

one_day = timedelta(days=1)

with open('times.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('times_updated.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for row in csv_input:
        arrival_time = datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(row[0], row[1]), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
        departure_time = datetime.strptime('{} {}'.format(row[2], row[3]), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')

        if departure_time < arrival_time:
            departure_time += one_day
            row[2] = departure_time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This would give you an output CSV file containing:

```
#Arrival_Date#,#Arrival_Time#,#Departure_Date#,#Departure_Time#
2017/01/01,23:30,2017/01/02,00:30
2017/02/01,23:30,2017/02/01,23:40
2017/03/01,15:45,2017/03/01,17:30
2017/04/10,23:50,2017/04/11,00:30
```

Note, this assumes you are using Python 3.x and that your CSV files are formatted as normal CSV files, i.e.  `aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd`